# drafts.create in objective-c using GTLQueryGmail

Tags: objective-c, gmail-api, google-schemas

I seem to be confused on how to use *GTMMIMEDocument.h* to set the raw message data for a new draft. In the example I'll post below I'm trying to set the headers for To, From and Subject but they seem to end up in the message body data instead of with the other headers.
Any help on what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Query method:

```
//message body to save
NSData *messageBody = [self.messagebox.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//create mimemessage
GTMMIMEDocument *email = [GTMMIMEDocument MIMEDocument];
NSArray *headers = @[@"To",@"From",@"Subject"];
NSArray *values = @[@"listserveproject2014dh@googlegroups.com",self.auth.userEmail,@"test email"];
NSDictionary *partheaders = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:headers];
[email addPartWithHeaders:partheaders body:messageBody];

//generate input stream
NSInputStream *inputstream = nil;
unsigned long long length = nil;
NSString *boundary = [[NSString alloc] init];
[email generateInputStream:&inputstream length:&length boundary:&boundary];

//get rawdata
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
[inputstream read:buffer maxLength:NSUIntegerMax];
NSData *rawdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:length];

//create query
GTLGmailDraft *draft = [[GTLGmailDraft alloc] init];
GTLGmailMessage *message = [[GTLGmailMessage alloc] init];

message.raw = GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawdata);
draft.message = message;

//GTLUploadParameters *parameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:rawdata MIMEType:@"message/rfc822"];
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersDraftsCreateWithUploadParameters:nil];
query.draft = draft;

...execute query
```

This is the response it gets:

```
{
"id": "r-2881802111797802342",
"message": {
 "id": "149a2aa34d4def95",
 "threadId": "149a2aa34d4def95",
 "labelIds": [
   "DRAFT"
 ],
 "snippet": "--END_OF_PART From: dhill4554@gmail.com Subject: test email To: listserveproject2014dh@googlegroups.",
 "historyId": "919257",
 "payload": {
   "partId": "",
   "mimeType": "text/plain",
   "filename": "",
   "headers": [
    {
     "name": "Received",
     "value": "from 58891527906-b79qq2lqjudtsj32n8ldpkup78uquol6.apps.googleusercontent.com named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Tue, 11 Nov 2014 22:21:43 -0800"
    },
    {
     "name": "Date",
     "value": "Tue, 11 Nov 2014 22:21:43 -0800"
    },
    {
     "name": "Message-Id",
     "value": "<CAOabQUdz8wzxQ29HbJq6xeRsSuu1iH6iRi9=A23vYHJencNdoQ@mail.gmail.com>"
    },
    {
     "name": "From",
     "value": "dhill4554@gmail.com"
    }
   ],
"body": {
  "size": 136,
  "data":  "LS1FTkRfT0ZfUEFSVA0KRnJvbTogZGhpbGw0NTU0QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ0KU3ViamVjdDogdGVzdCBlbWFpbA0KVG86IGxpc3RzZXJ2ZXByb2plY3QyMDE0ZGhAZ29vZ2xlZ3JvdXBzLmNvbQ0KDQptZXNzYWdlDQotLUVORF9PRl9QQVJULS0NCg=="
 }
},
"sizeEstimate": 466
}
}
```

And here's what the raw data looks like decoded(the message body is "message"):

```
--END_OF_PART
From: dhill4554@gmail.com
Subject: test email
To: listserveproject2014dh@googlegroups.com

message
--END_OF_PART--
```

Comment: got it to work, just had to get rid of the boundaries

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer please? What do you mean by you got rid of the boundary?

Comment: --
To: chinnasamymca@yahoo.com
From: dhill4554@gmail.com
Subject: Need help on google-API on iOS to send email

message body goes here
--

Note that the "--" marks are not actually included. This would work for a plain text email

Comment: I'm not sure if you can tell whats happening in that comment. Shoot me an email or something and I can go into more detail.

Comment: Hi Drew, eventually, I figured it out... Like you said, I had to stop the google's wrapper library from adding the boundary "--END_OF_PART--" to the raw message.  I was using the 'prebuilt framework' earlier, that's why I could not spot this 'boundary'. I have no idea why it is adding that boundary since it is not removing it at the other end. Thus, the end result was not adhering to rfc2822. Thanks anyways. Appreciate it.