# How send Email using Gmail api in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, email, gmail-api

The [Gmail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) has no clear documentation on how to do this, I have been trying with [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) but there are many things that are in the air.

I have sought external sources such. [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824036/how-to-insert-a-mail-using-the-latest-gmail-api-in-swift) and [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881735/drafts-create-in-objective-c-using-gtlquerygmail). The first seems to use the potential of the api, using the function `queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters`.

While the second is about a little more. Although this in Objective-C is not a problem, except for the GTMMIMEDocument object, which do not know where or if it is obtained or a library.

My question is if someone has a somewhat cleaner and / or code easier to understand, or a better guide in which to send an email

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution

```
class func sendEmail() {

        var gtlMessage = GTLGmailMessage()
        gtlMessage.raw = self.generateRawString()

        let appd = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters(nil)
        query.message = gtlMessage

        appd.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, response, error) -> Void in
            println("ticket \(ticket)")
            println("response \(response)")
            println("error \(error)")
        })
    }

    class func generateRawString() -> String {

        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //RFC2822-Format
        var todayString:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

        var rawMessage = "" +
            "Date: \(todayString)\r\n" +
            "From: <mail>\r\n" +
            "To: username <mail>\r\n" +
            "Subject: Test send email\r\n\r\n" +
            "Test body"

        println("message \(rawMessage)")

        return GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind you have to "#import "GTLBase64.h" in your bridging header file.

Comment: Thanks for the post!

Comment: What if Email Message Body has HTML content? Above answer is working fine for Plain Text messages only. For messages with HTML Tags the mail is being sent but when received it shows raw HTML tags as it is, instead of proper HTML output.

Comment: Gmail API for iOS is clumsy. I added pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST' and added few generated gmail files. I'm not even able to declare var gtlMessage = GTLGmailMessage(). Any help?

Comment: GMail API for iOS is a complete mess. I'm stuck here trying to get authorization for API calls after importing the GoogleAPIClientForREST / Gmail. Its documentation is essentially non existent

Comment: please can you show how you Authorized the GTLRGmailService service

Comment: I eventually found a super cool and super simple library that wraps all the Obj C inconsistency and exposes a simple interface. Thank and Bless the Author: Jonas-Taha El Sesiy . GitHub: github.com/elsesiy/GAppAuth

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to send an email I suggest using the [MailCore](http://libmailcore.com) library for iOS.
In the documentation there are examples just in Objective-c but it is compatible with Swift

This is an example of how to send an email with MailCore and Swift:

```
var smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpSession.username = "matt@gmail.com"
smtpSession.password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
smtpSession.port = 465
smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.SASLPlain
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
    if data != nil {
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
            NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
        }
    }
}

var builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Rool", mailbox: "itsrool@gmail.com")]
builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Matt R", mailbox: "matt@gmail.com")
builder.header.subject = "My message"
builder.htmlBody = "Yo Rool, this is a test message!"

let rfc822Data = builder.data()
let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperationWithData(rfc822Data)
sendOperation.start { (error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("Error sending email: \(error)")
    } else {
        NSLog("Successfully sent email!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

But I need to use gmail api for this. Since the application is fully linked with gmail. To get and send emails, and most importantly is that I need the gmail id generated for logic subsequent

Comment: Quick side note if you're using MailCore, sometimes gmail may prevent logging in, then you have to go to your gmail account and enable [this](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution I have finally make it work :

Podfile :

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Gmail'
```

Sample Swift 5 code:

```
import Foundation
import GoogleAPIClient

class GMailManager {

    let service = GTLServiceGmail()

    func sendEmail() {

        guard let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersMessagesSend(with: nil) else {
            return
        }

        let gtlMessage = GTLGmailMessage()
        gtlMessage.raw = self.generateRawString()

        query.message = gtlMessage

        self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, response, error) -> Void in
            print("ticket \(String(describing: ticket))")
            print("response \(String(describing: response))")
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        })
    }

    func generateRawString() -> String {

        let dateFormatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //RFC2822-Format
        let todayString:String = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)

        let rawMessage = "" +
            "Date: \(todayString)\r\n" +
            "From: <mail>\r\n" +
            "To: username <mail>\r\n" +
            "Subject: Test send email\r\n\r\n" +
            "Test body"

        print("message \(rawMessage)")

        return GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cockurt, I try to use your code and I am getting following error, can you please describe briefly. Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "(Login Required)"

Answer (score 0):

According to Google API documentation(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending), we can know there are have two ways can help you send message success(draft.send, message.send). without a doubt, both of them use api are different, but the result is the same. 
As you give one of the above way can got that, we just call it message.send. With another way is draft.send, so we should upload "UploadParameters" to Gmail draft, after we upload success, we can get some message about gmail draft. At last, we should send mail content, when we send success, the draft message will automatic delete. Code goes be as follows:

```
func postEmailMessageRequest(model: MEMailMessageModel, request: CompletionRequest) {

        let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters()
        uploadParameters.data = model.snippet.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        uploadParameters.MIMEType = model.mimeType!

        let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersDraftsCreateWithUploadParameters(uploadParameters) as! GTLQueryProtocol!
        service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket : GTLServiceTicket!, messages : AnyObject!, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let messages = (messages as! GTLGmailDraft)
                messages.message.threadId = model.threadID
                self.sendMailRequest(messages, model: model, request: request)
            } else {
                request(status: false, result: "upload success")
            }
        }
    }

    func sendMailRequest(draft: GTLGmailDraft, model: MEMailMessageModel, request: CompletionRequest) {

        let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersDraftsSendWithUploadParameters(nil) as! GTLQueryGmail
        draft.message.raw = self.generateRawString(model)
        query.draft = draft

        self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, response, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                request(status: true, result: "send success") // after this, the draft will be delete
            } else {
                request(status: false, result: "send failure")
            }
        })
    }

    func generateRawString(model: MEMailMessageModel) -> String {
        let date = MEMailMessagelFormatUtil.coverDateFromDate(NSDate(), dateFormat: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")! // get current date

        var fromEamil = ""
        if let str = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userEmail") as? String {
            fromEamil = str
        }

        var rawMessage = ""
        if model.isReply { // how to reply, but how to reply the email is another question.
            rawMessage = "" + "In-Reply-To: \(model.messageID!)\r\n"
            if let references = model.references {
                rawMessage += "References: \(references) \(model.messageID!)\r\n"
            } else {
                rawMessage += "References: \(model.messageID!)\r\n"
            }
        }

        rawMessage += "Date: \(date)\r\n" +
            "From: <\(fromEamil)>\r\n" +
            "To: \(model.toName!) <\(model.toMail)>\r\n" +
            "Subject: \(model.subject) \r\n\r\n" + "\(model.snippet)"

        return GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
```

Comment: Any example for add attachment to mail?

Comment: I'll looking to add an attachment as well.  Did anyone ever figure this out for Gmail API and SWIFT?

Comment: I get an error for MEMailMessageModel "Use of undeclared type MEMailMessageModel.  What do I need to add to support i?

Comment: as you see, 'MEMailMessageModel' is self custom model. just say you should create you model and base contains (threadID, messageID, references, subject, fromUserInformation, toUserInformation)