# How to Send HTML Rich Message using GTLGmailMessage

Tags: ios, swift, gmail-api

I am using `gmail API` where I send email using `GTLGmailMessage`.
When I try to send normal Text message by setting it to `GTLGmailMessage.raw` it's being sent successfully.

I tried same code with HTML rich content. It's sending mail successfully but html content source is being displayed in received email.

Here is my code to prepare raw email body:

```
private func generateRawString() -> String {

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //RFC2822-Format
let todayString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

let externalDataSource = self.emailActivity.storedInServerFolder?.forEmailAccount?.externalDataSource
let senderEmail: String = (externalDataSource?.userName)!
let senderName: String = (emailActivity.activityOwner?.leFullName)!

var rawMessage = ""
var bodyText = ""
var bodyHTML = ""

rawMessage = rawMessage + "Date: \(todayString)\r\n"
rawMessage = rawMessage + "From: \(senderName) <\(senderEmail)>\r\n"
rawMessage = rawMessage + addParticipants(with: Constants.ActivityRoleTypes.kKeyActivityTypeEmailRoleTo, roleType: "To: ")
rawMessage = rawMessage + addParticipants(with: Constants.ActivityRoleTypes.kKeyActivityTypeEmailRoleCc, roleType: "Cc: ")
rawMessage = rawMessage + addParticipants(with: Constants.ActivityRoleTypes.kKeyActivityTypeEmailRoleBcc, roleType: "Bcc: ")
rawMessage = rawMessage + "Subject: \((emailActivity.activityName)!)\r\n\r\n"

if let actDesc = emailActivity.activityDescription{
    bodyText = actDesc
    bodyText = bodyText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
}
if let htmlContent = emailActivity.activityHtmlContent {
    bodyHTML = htmlContent
}

var finalHTMLBody = self.createHTMLBody(bodyText: bodyText, htmlContent: bodyHTML)
finalHTMLBody += "\r\n\r\n" + Constants.PLACE_HOLDERS.kEmailDraftBody

rawMessage = rawMessage + finalHTMLBody

return GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

This is the reference link for Code I am using to send mail.
[How send Email using Gmail api in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259916/how-send-email-using-gmail-api-in-swift)

Googled a lot. Is there any encoding/decoding left for html specific part?

Thanks in advance.

Reference: Also Created Issue in the Github Library being used: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/issues/206

Comment: There's a tutorial from the CtrlQ site on how to [Use Gmail API to Send Rich Text Emails](https://ctrlq.org/code/19860-gmail-api-send-emails). It's written in PHP tho so you have to infer what you can from the code sample. I read you have to encode the message in Base64URL.

Comment: @noogui: Please note that I am already applying Base 64 encoding at the very end to entire Message before setting it to message.raw

GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(rawMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))